# Tooltip not showing on second validation failure

Tags: jquery

I'm using Tipso tool-tip plugin for my validation error messages with regex validation, it works pretty good when entering invalid characters at first but when entering invalid characters after valid characters it's showing its default blank green tool-tip.

Examples:

1. Invalid + Valid characters (Working as expected)

[image]

2. Valid + Invalid characters (Not working-Showing its default green tooltip)

[image]

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").on('input',function () {
       if(/\D/g.test(this.value))
          {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
            $(this).tipso({
            content: "Invalid Number!",
            background: '#FFFAF0',
            color: '#000000',
            width : 150,
            delay : 50,
            position :'bottom'}).tipso('show');
          }
          else {
               $(this).tipso('hide');
               }
           });
      });
```

I want to show tool-tip even after typing valid+invalid characters same time.

Comment: if(/\D/g.test(this.value)) what is this

Comment: It's a metacharacter in RegExp to find a non-digit character.

Comment: @dılosürücü It's a condition to find a non-digit character if found it will return false and will show a message in  tool-tip

Comment: Look at the debug of browser ..it will help u

Comment: @dılosürücü Not found any clue, is my script correct? Show() hide() methods? Or I'm missing any condition?